# How to make Redis notify my service about events

Tags: c#, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a remote computer with Redis. From time to time new entries are added to it (key-value pair). I want Redis to send notifications to my C# Service about events like this (i'm interested in value part). I've searched online and found simple code example to subscribe my Service to Redis. How to make Redis send notifications?

Service:

```
public partial class ResultsService : ServiceBase
{
    private ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisConnection"]);

    private const string ChatChannel = "__keyspace@0__:*";

    public VerificationResultsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var pubsub = connection.GetSubscriber();

        pubsub.Subscribe(ChatChannel, (channel, message) => MessageAction(message));

        while (true)
        {

        }
    }

    private static void MessageAction(RedisValue message)
    {
         // some handler...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making redis send *automatic keyspace* notifications is a redis server configuration piece, which can be enabled via the .conf file (`notify-keyspace-events`), or via `CONFIG SET` at runtime; the documentation for this [is here](https://redis.io/topics/notifications).

You can see how this works with example code:

```cs
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class P
{
    private const string ChatChannel = "__keyspace@0__:*";
    static void Main()
    {
        // connect (allowAdmin just lets me use ConfigSet)
        using var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1,allowAdmin=true");

        // turn on all notifications; note that this is server-wide
        // and is NOT just specific to our connection/code
        muxer.GetServer(muxer.GetEndPoints().Single())
             .ConfigSet("notify-keyspace-events", "KEA"); // KEA=everything

        // subscribe to the event
        muxer.GetSubscriber().Subscribe(ChatChannel,
            (channel, message) => Console.WriteLine($"received {message} on {channel}"));

        // stop the client from exiting
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

which works like:

[image]

---

However, in many scenarios you may find that this is too "noisy", and you may prefer to use either a custom named event that you publish *manually* when you do things that need notification, or (again manually) you could make use of the [streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) features to consume a flow of data (streams can be treated as a flow of events in the "things that happened" sense, but they are not delivered via pub/sub).

Comment: thank you for answer. At the moment, I have executed the command CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEs, but still do not receive any notifications. Maybe I subscribe to the wrong channel?

Comment: @Fallingsappy I copied and pasted the channel in a demo I put together (see edit); it should work fine...

Comment: Yep, example works good, one more question, i'm confused sooo, i'm getting some records like this:
"received 8744f3fb-7244-476a-9eb1-1df4cdd177ed on __keyevent@0__:hset"
i think this guidlike number is key in redis. I learned from documentation, that i can get value with it. So i thougth: muxer.GetDatabase().StringGet("8744f3fb-7244-476a-9eb1-1df4cdd177ed") would work, but it doesn't because guidlike number is a redisvalue not rediskey